# How to send multiple values of checkbox to back-end in param=value1%2Cvalue2 format?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I have a checkboxlist in my form as following, which I do not know whats the best way to receive its selected options in back-end.

```
<s:form id="search" name="search" method="GET" action="search">
    <s:checkboxlist name="mySearch.age" label="Age" list="@com.example.Lists@AGE"/>
    <s:checkboxlist name="mySearch.gender" label="Gender" list="@com.example.Lists@GENDER"/>
    <s:select name="mySearch.education"  label="Education" list="@com.example.Lists@EDUCATION"/>
    <s:select name="mySearch.country" label="Country" list="@com.example.Lists@COUNTRY"/>
    <s:textfield id="mySearch.terms" name="mySearch.terms" label="Terms (Separate by comma)"/>
  <s:submit value="Submit"/>
</s:form>
```

I am not sure what the type of age should be and how to catch it in back-end.

I need them to be as following or any other format to be easy to search based on them

```
   age=20%2C30 or age=20,30
```

**1)** At the moment it is like following

```
  private List<Integer> age;
```

and the values will be as follwoing in the url,

```
   mySearch.age=20&mySearch.age=30
```

**2)** I used javascript function and simple html (same as [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_checkbox)) to send the values as well using following code but it sends them as age=20&age=30

```
     $('#search').serialize()
```

**3)** I also used the following code to send them as age=2,3 which is fine but I am wondering how to send the values of other fields of the form along with these values?

```
var formValues = $('#search').serialize();
    var obj={};
    obj.ages = $('input[name=age]:checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    alert(obj.ages);
```

Comment: model driven is not complex rather its eazy to divide code into modules

Comment: what are other fields you want to send with age?

Comment: @Rembo question is updated

Comment: why dont you use model class for data receving?

Comment: Why do you want it be in that format?

Comment: @A5l-lE5 the first problem is how to send the parameters to back-end. Once they are sent I can catch them using any method.

Comment: @AleksandrM I suppose thats the standard practice to pass them as age=20,30 etc rather than mySearch.age=20&mySearch.age=30, another reason is that parameters will be appended to the address bar before being sent back to the back-end, so it is better to send them in a shorter format to make the address simpler. Consider following www.example.com?age=20%2C30 versus www.example.com?mySearch.age=20&mySearch.age=30

Comment: you can bind the values in arraylist in action class and get the values on submit also you can use javascript to get checkbox values ?where you getting stukked?

Comment: @A5l-lE5 as explained, once I use List<Integer> age; the values will be passed as mySearch.age=20&mySearch.age=30 , I need them to be passed as age=20%20C30 or age=20,30, please read my explanation for AleksandrM

Comment: instead of passing them with comma serated you can try for url rewrting

Comment: @A5l-lE5 if I try url rewriting I would need to change the url mapping of the whole application which I do not want to.

Comment: @A5l-lE5 that is checkbox mine is checkboxlist! Also, I've followed the checkboxlist tutorial of mkyong but could not find an answer for the issue.

Comment: @JackMoore: *Standard practice* is send parameters as `mySearch.age=20&mySearch.age=30`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost there.

`$.serialize()` simply returns a string, so you can then manipulate it like you would any other string.

```
var formValues = $('#search input, #search select, #search textarea').not("[name='age']").serialize();
var ages = $('input[name=age]:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
formValues += "&age=" + ages;
alert(formValues);
```

The first line serializes all fields EXCEPT age. Then we simply add age to the string, and send that final string to the server.

If you have other fields with multiple values, simply extend `.not("[name='age'], [name='otherfield']")` to include these other fields, and repeat the process above.

**Edit**: Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bUQ4b/

Answer (score 0):

Although (as Aleksandr commented) this is not standard practice, I think you could achieve your goal by:

1. Adding a new **hidden** field to your form, let's say *mySearch.ages*
2. onSubmit iterate over the checked mySearch.age fields, concatenate the results and add them as value to *mySearch.ages*
3. Disable all mySearch.age inputs
4. Then serialize/submit as usual

Let me know if this is working as expected or you need more help with this.

Answer (score 0):

If the concern is to make it easier to build a list on the server side, you could just do this:

```
String[] ages = request.getParameterValues("age");
if(ages!=null)
{
    List<Integer> listAgesInt = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    try
    {
        for(String s : ages )
        {
           listAgesInt.add(Integer.valueOf(s));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        out.print("Error converting to integer");
    }
    for(int i : listAgesInt )
    {
       out.print("<br/>" + i);
    }
}
```

Then you don't need to change how the browser sends the data.  You can easily make that into a function that takes in a `String[]` and returns a `List<Integer>`.   Then you would just call  `List<Integer> listAgesInt = somelib.funcname(request.getParameterValues("age"));`

Comment: My concern is server side and simplicity of the request on the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", "a.downloadAllFile", function() {
    var db = $('.childcheckbox:checked').map(function(i,n) {
        return $(n).val();
    }).get(); //get converts it to an array

    if(db.length == 0) { 
        db = "none"; 
    }
    console.log(db);
    $.post(url, {'db[]': db}, function(response) {
        $("#dbdisplay").html(response); 
    });
    return true;
});
```

Comment: there are lots of other fields on the form, it is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

> how to send the values of other fields of the form along with these
>   values?

you can send all fields value by using JSON data format, to send JSON add this jquery helper function to create JSON object from form elements:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

then on form submit create JSON object like:

```
$(function() {
    $('form#search').submit(function() {
        var sendData = {};
        sendData["searchModel"] = $(':input:visible', this).serializeObject();
        $('#input').text(JSON.stringify(sendData));
        $.ajax({
            url : "writeJSON",
            type : 'POST',
            data : JSON.stringify(sendData),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",                       
            success : function(res) {
                console.log('success');
                $('#output').text(JSON.stringify(res));             
            },error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error: '+textStatus+' : '+ errorThrown);
            }
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here, `$(':input:visible', this).serializeObject();` will return only visible elements value that is all check box checked value, select box selected options, and text input value etc. also note here AJAX method is `POST`.

Create a model bean to serialize and deserialize JSON by using [struts2-json-plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-json-plugin) like:

```
public class SearchModel {

    private Integer[] ages;
    private String gender;
    private String education;
    private String country;
    private String terms;

    //getters, setters and constructor
}
```

Action class will look like:

```
public class SearchAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private SearchModel searchModel;

    public String readJSON() {
            //do your work here..
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String writeJSON() {     
        System.out.println("writeJSON Method invoked");
        System.out.println(searchModel);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    // SearchModel getter and setter

}
```

in `struts.xml` configure to return and receive json result like:

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">     

       <interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="json">
                <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
       </interceptors>
       <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

       <action name="writeJSON" class="com.actions.SearchAction" method="writeJSON">          
          <result type="json"/>
       </action>
       <action name="readJSON" class="com.actions.SearchAction" method="readJSON">          
          <result type="json"/>
       </action>

</package>
```

and in jsp form:

```
<s:form id="search">
    <s:checkboxlist name="ages"
                    label="Age" list="ages"/>
    <s:checkboxlist name="gender"
                    label="Gender" list="genders"/>
    <s:select name="education"
                label="Education" list="educations"/>
    <s:select name="country" 
                label="Country" list="countrys"/>
    <s:textfield id="terms"
                name="terms" label="Terms (Separate by comma)"/>
  <s:submit value="Submit"/>
</s:form>
Input:
 <div id="input"></div>
Output:
 <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I suppose this method is against general practice.

Answer (score 0):

When multiple checkboxes are checked, you can assign them to String and Integer arrays in your scenario. For example if your age list has options:10, 20, 30 and 40 of which 10,20 are selected, you can store them in Integer array as comma seperated 10,20 and retieve it in action by their getters.
For eg.,

```
    <s:form id="search" name="search" method="GET" action="search">
        <s:checkboxlist name="age" label="Age" list="ageList"/>
        <s:checkboxlist name="gender" label="Gender" list="genderList"/>
        <s:select name="education"  label="Education" list="educationList"/>
        <s:select name="country" label="Country" list="countryList"/>
      <s:submit value="Submit"/>
    </s:form>
```

In your search form where  you capture these values, specify them as arrays:

```
public Integer[] age;
public String[] gender;
public String[] education;
public String[] country;
//Mutators for these
```

Also, make sure genderList, educationList,countryList are populated.